# Como salvar Base64 em ImageFiled Django / data:image/jpeg;base64,?

Tags: ionic, django, base64

Eu estou tentando salvar uma imagem de base64 no meu modelo , mas não conseguir.

Meu código é;

Modelo:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'pic_folder')

view:

@csrf_exempt
def imageUP(request):
    img = request.GET['img']
    image_data = b64decode(img)

    image_name = str(uuid.uuid4()) + ".jpeg"

    x = Image()
    x.img = ContentFile(image_data, image_name)
    x.save()

    return HttpResponse("Upload completed")
```

Minha base64 String é:

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,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
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: É relevante usar o base64 somente na exibição, senão esse pug aí do exemplo vai ocupar 1/3 a mais do que precisa se for armazenado desta forma.

Answer (score 0):

Remova o `data:image/jpeg;base64,` da sua string antes de usar o *b64decode*.

```
img = request.GET['img'].replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,','')
```

Answer (score -1):

Você pode utilizar uma função para converter o base64 para imagem:

```
def base64_str_to_image(base64_str):
    # format recebe o que vem antes do ;base64; e imgstr o que vem depois
    # ou seja, format recebe a extensão e imgstr a imagem
    format, imgstr = base64_str.split(';base64,')
    ext = format.split('/')[-1]
    # gerando uuid para nomes únicos nas imagens
    # para que não haja conflito nos updates
    name = uuid.uuid4()
    # converte uuid para string
    name = str(name)
    # cria o nome da imagem + a extensão
    name_ext = name + '.' + ext
    image = ContentFile(base64.b64decode(imgstr), name=name_ext)
    return image, name_ext
```